# iPhone 6 Plus support fonts issue

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, iphone-6-plus, size-classes

I'm starting on adding iPhone 6 support for my app.
I don't want to use Size Classes since the app runs on iOS7 as well.
I'm planning on using auto-layout for views positioning but I'm not sure how to handle font sizes.
I want to make some of the fonts bigger on iPhone 6 plus.
How can I do that using Auto-Layout without Size Classes?

Comment: Maybe writing some code to enlarge the font size will help you?...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid code like if iPhone5, if iPhone6, iPhone6Plus

Comment: Then, put different nib file for iPhone 6+.

Comment: That will defeat the whole purpose of Auto Layout

Comment: Then write some code :)

Comment: Again - I'm trying to avoid code like if iPhone5, if iPhone6, iPhone6Plus...

Comment: For me the fatest solution would be to add some code that will fit the font size relatively to its label bounds. -- easy and device independent , like if tomorrow will be iphone 9 with 50' screen this code will still work if the label view bounds are correct

Comment: Please refer to the link: [Dynamic Font Size for UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504186/how-to-increase-fonts-and-sizes-on-plus-device-in-swift/47508648#47508648)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `size classes` and support iOS7, it's an `Xcode` related feature to help you design the behaviour of your app.

Get the latest version of `Xcode`, set the `deployment target` to `iOS7` and start designing your `ViewController's` using size class.