# How to increase fonts and sizes on plus device in Swift?

Tags: ios, autolayout, splash-screen, iphone-6-plus

I observed some popular apps. When we compare iPhone Plus devices and normal devices, fonts and images are varying. A little bit bigger in iPhone Plus device. How can we achieve same in our iOS applications? I already used splash screens. But still fonts are same, no difference in plus and normal devices.

**Note**: By resolution differentiate in coding is working fine. But I'm looking for other alternative ways like either in adaptive layouts nor launch screens.

Comment: You can just use big font on your project, then set number of lines with auto scale, it will scale down the font via the size of the label

Comment: you can use size class to archive that

Comment: @SagarBhut Can you please assist me, How to achieve with size classes.

Comment: @Tj3n what do you mean set number of lines with auto scale. Number lines is a number. we need to set 0 or some lines. So can you please give some reference links for that.

Comment: It's called `Auto Shrink` in storyboard, if your number of lines is different than 0, it will shrink your label font to match the width of label

Comment: @Tj3n Then how image sizes are increasing in other apps. By using launch screen not helps anything.

Comment: Image size then even easier, it can be constrained to view's height/width, it will always be the same ratio if you set

Comment: @Tj3n cool, then i will check it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it withing your interface builder(xib or storyboard)!

Select your label or text field etc and go to `attribute inspector`.

Near `font` you will find `+` button, click it, select your variation (size class) and set different font for that particular size class.

Refer below screenshot for better understanding,

[image]

Reference : [Size classes in Interface Builder in Xcode 8](https://medium.com/@craiggrummitt/size-classes-in-interface-builder-in-xcode-8-74f20a541195)

For example `Compact width, Regular height` this variation or size class is for all iphones in portrait mode!

you can refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html) for more details about size classes!

Second thing you can do that is set `autoshrink` to `minimum font scale` and set that font scale between `0 to 1`.

and then set larger font(maximum font size that you want to show in plus or pro devices for your app) in your interface builder. Now, when your app will get open in small size device, your font size will be try to reduce with that minimum scale factor. for example if you have set scale factor `0.5` and your font size is 100 in storyboard then in small device it will try to reduce font size till 50 to fit in label or textfield.

[image]

Comment: w:R h:R is not for iPhone, it represents iPad pro. But i need for iPhone plus portrait mode. We have size class for iPhone landscape mode but not portrait mode.

Comment: w:C, h:R is for iphone in portrait mode!

Comment: w:C, h:R is common for all iPhones. But my question is how can we increase font for iPhone plus devices compare to normal devices. if you compare some popular apps like facebook and other apps. their fonts are increased a bit bigger than normal devices.

Comment: You can not differentiate iphone plus devices by size classes. you can take look in another solution of autoshrinkiing!

Comment: The first half of your answer (size classes) is irrelevant to the question, and is likely to confuse people.

Answer (score 2):

Just create custom class for each controller. Below, I am create csutom class for `UIButton`, You can also create same for other control.

**HSCustomButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HSCustomButton : UIButton

@end
```

**HSCustomButton.m**

```
#import "HSCustomButton.h"
#define SCALE_FACTOR_H ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 667) 


@implementation HSCustomButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if( (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) ){
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
        [self configurefont];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) configurefont {
    CGFloat newFontSize = (self.titleLabel.font.pointSize * SCALE_FACTOR_H);
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.titleLabel.font.fontName size:newFontSize];
}
@end
```

Just change class name in storyboard, then font scale automatically for all other device.

Answer (score 0):

Create category class of UILabel or any other control (UIButton , UITextField , etc).

**UILabel+DynamicFontSize.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface UILabel (DynamicFontSize)
 @property (nonatomic) IBInspectable BOOL adjustFontSize;
 @end
```

**UILabel+DynamicFontSize.m**

```
 #import "UILabel+DynamicFontSize.h"

 @implementation UILabel (DynamicFontSize)
 @dynamic adjustFontSize;
 -(void)setAdjustFontSize:(BOOL)adjustFontSize{
     if (adjustFontSize)
     {
        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:self.font.pointSize*(screenBounds.size.width/320)]; // 320 for iPhone 5(320x568) storyboard design
        // if you design with iphone 6(375x667) in storyboard, use 375 instead of 320 and iphone 6 plus(414x736), use 414
     }
   }
 @end
```

**Usage**

Select any label and find property name Adjust Font Size change value to ON

[image]